# swift - HomeKit updateTargetValue of HMCharacteristicWriteAction crashes

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, homekit, nscopying

I am trying to update target value of an action (`HMCharacteristicWriteAction`) but it always crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50).

My code snippet:

```
print("\(action) --> \(action.dynamicType)") // <HMCharacteristicWriteAction: 0x14cf7ba20> --> HMCharacteristicWriteAction
print("current: \(action.targetValue)") // current: 1
print("next: \(value) --> \(value.dynamicType)") // next: 0 --> Int

action.updateTargetValue(value, completionHandler: { [weak self] error -> Void in
       if let error = error {
           // display some message
           return
       }

       // do something else when succeeded
})
```

As you see, `action` is not nil and of correct type (`HMCharacteristicWriteAction`). I can read its `targetValue` successfully.

I analyzed the project using `Product - Analyze`, everything is ok (no any warnings). I also enabled Zombie in `Scheme - Diagnostics` but still no luck.

---

According to `updateTargetValue` documentation:

```
/*!
 * @brief This method is used to change target value for the characteristic.
 *
 * @param targetValue New target value for the characteristic.
 *
 * @param completion Block that is invoked once the request is processed. 
 *                   The NSError provides more information on the status of the request, error
 *                   will be nil on success.
 */
public func updateTargetValue(targetValue: NSCopying, completionHandler completion: (NSError?) -> Void)
```

What confuses me is `targetValue: NSCopying`. Does type `Int` of `value` conform 'NSCopying'? I did try `value as NSCopying` for `targetValue` but it is not better.

Could you please show me how to solve this problem? Is it ok to pass an `Int` to `targetValue`? What could cause this crash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An Int does not conform to NSCopying, use an NSNumber instead which does conform to NSCopying.

To convert an Int to NSNumber use

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)];
```

or

```
SWIFT
    init(int value: Int32)
OBJECTIVE-C
- (NSNumber *)initWithInt:(int)value
```

Comment: hi Maria, I did try NSNumber but things are not improved. My code is `let targetValue = NSNumber(integer: value)`, then `actionSet.updateTargetValue(targetValue, ...` --> still crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0x50)`.